# Left outer join with 3 tables and subquery

Tags: join, db2

sorry for the late response.

For a key in table A, there may be 2 or more records present in tables B and C. That is, one another column in these tables will have a date value which would be making the keys unique. So I want to extract the record that has maximum date value. And that's why I am using the max function. I know that the subquery which I have coded should not be included in the ON clause and it would do the filtering before the join statement. So eventually I want to know how to mention the max clause in the query.

Example:
Table A
Key - AAAAA

Table B:
Record 1
Key - AAAAA
Date - 2017-10-01

Record 2
Key - AAAAA
Date - 2017-10-05

I want the only the record AAAAA/2017-10-05 to be selected from the table B

Basically records from table A where A.c3 = 'Y' should be extracted first (assume it gives 500 records)
Then join these 500 records with tables B and C (left outer, to have all the matching records and the non-matching records should have nulls in the columns from the tables B and C)
In tables B and C, if more than 1 record present with different dates, the maximum date field should be extracted.

Hence final output should contain 500 records.

Comment: I don't understand what this query is supposed to be doing. Maybe you should update your question and show us some sample data.

Comment: _Edit_ your question and show sample input data along with the output you expect.

Comment: It looks like you might also trying to do some form of [tag:greatest-n-per-group] , although sample and desired data would _greatly_ help us here.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need for what you describe

```
SELECT A.A1, A.A2, B.B1, B.B2, C.C1, C.C2 
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.A1 = B.B1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 C
ON A.A1 = C.C1
WHERE A.C3 = ‘Y’
```

These lines are causing your problem...basically forcing your outer joins to an inner joins.

```
AND B.C3 = (SELECT MAX(B3) FROM TABLE2 T1
        WHERE T1.B1 = B.B1)
AND C.C3 = (SELECT MAX(C3) FROM TABLE3 T1
        WHERE T1.C1 = C.C1)
```

If there's no match in B or C , then B.C3 and/or C.C3 will be NULL and NULL can't be = to anything (or <> to anything for that matter)

What are you trying to accomplish with the above that you've not included in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Just do it?

```
SELECT A.A1, A.A2, B.B1, B.B2, C.C1, C.C2 
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.A1 = B.B1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 C
ON A.A1 = C.C1
WHERE A.C3 = 'Y' and (B.B1 is null or C.B1 is null)
```

Comment: if you want I can create a new question so you get credit (trying to keep everything together).  When joining 3 or more tables, when combining/using the ON part,  are there any restrictions?  Like we should only use stuff from the left table with parts from the right table?
When joining A > B > C.   Is there a hierarchy?  Like the part where C is joined must be linked to B (or can we join A to B and also join A to C simultaneously)?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_joindatafromtables.html  Thanks!